# QC/Quality Control with Python Scripts

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, validation

I used to work for a company that loaded and transformed data using SQL. It would insert different stats about the process into a QC table for that particular script. So things like rowcounts, run date, run time, etc would all be stored. After running the process, you could compare your run's stats to previous runs to make sure everything went smoothly.

I'm now using Python to load and process data and am trying to come up with a solution for QC. I considered just using pysql and inserting to a SQL table, but I've found I have different data types that don't do well inside a sql table. I'd like to preserve data types, like small dictionaries and lists and whatnot as opposed to converting it all to text/varchar.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why would the data types be different. Aren't all scripts going to have rowcount, run date, run time which are just integer, date/time? In any case, you could try json databases (I was using tinydb sometime back) to store different attributes per record.

Comment: @samik those aren't the only things that would be logged. There would be lots of other things, like lists, small dictionaries, and anything like that (a non-numeric field) just automatically gets converted to a string. When I pull it back in with python, it doesn't auto-convert back to the original dtype. I'll look into json databases though, thanks for the suggestion